# How can we restart webjobs after deployment?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

I have a WebApp in Azure. This webapp has several continuous nodeJS webjobs.

Main code of jobs is outside job dir (wwwroot/app_data/jobs/continuous/webjob-1). Every job is a run.js file with these lines:

```
const job = require('../../../../../jobs/webjob-1-maincode');
job.run();
```

Azure automatically restarts webjobs on deployment when it detects any change in job folder. But, in my case, webjob code under wwwroot does not change. File changes are in other folders. And for this reason, Azure does not restart my jobs on deployments.

I am deploying through git push.

How can we force Azure to restart these jobs on deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a [Kudu Custom Deployment Script](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1/), and add logic in there to explicitely touch some file in the jobs folder if you want it to be restarted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand it is not perfect, but nowadays is the only way. Here is official documentation: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script